# Comparing two listst of rows on different workbooks and updating list 2 with missing rows from list 1 - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, list, rows, updating

What i try to accomplish in Excel using VBA is to have a "original" workbook that is used to start with each time, adjusted and saved under a new name. This workbook, and all workbooks that come from it have a "client database" sheet where client data is automaticly copied in to (1 row per client, A:G). Whenever a original workbook is filled in the data is copied to the client database in that specific workbook, but then automaticly saved under another name.

Therefore i am looking for a code that opens the original workbook (done), compares the database sheet of the new file with the original and then updates the original with the new client data. (Best case they would update each other). What's important is that the whole row should be compared, as for instance one company can have different contacts.

Now my coding skills unfortunately aren't good enough to accomplish this, and i have browsed different topics to find a solution but wasn't able to find a solution that completely covers the problem (and is written simple enough for me to still understand).

Both sheets hold the same database structure and the tab is called "Klanten database".

If anyone would be able and willing to help that would be much appreciated!

I have already tried different codes from the forum, but they all focus on either columns or specific cells and are made to extract unique value's to a new list or just to highlight the differences. Or are to complicated for me to understand.. :X

````
Sub UpdateOriginal()
'Open original file to update

  Workbooks.Open Sheets("Data inhoud").Range("J12").Value & "\original.xlsm"

  'compare active database with original and update the both of them



Workbooks("original.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub```

None have worked :(
````

Comment: Create a data source connection to client list and automatically update Workbook, when opening file?

Comment: How many columns does it need to compare? Can't be all, right?

Comment: Yes, it needs to compare all colums and test if the entire row already excists or not.